# How to import two sets of data in the same excel sheet in R?

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, read.csv

Currently in one excel sheet I have one block of data that begins from row 1 and the last row always varies, but it is usually around 18 or 19. Once the first set of data ends then there are two blank rows and the second data set begins, which is also around 18 or 19. The two data sets have the same number of columns and share the same headers. I save the excel sheet as a csv. Then in R I will do `read.csv()`, but after I have done that I do not know how to separate the two sets of data into separate data.frames.

I realize I could just copy and paste the second data set into a separate excel sheet and read it in, but I do not want to do that. I want to leave the excel sheet untouched.

Example of the excel sheet:

```
A  B  C  D   # FIRST DATA SET
1  2  3  4


A  B  C  D   # SECOND DATA SET
5  6  7  8
```

Any help will be appreciated and please let me know if more info is needed.

Comment: You may want to add your data if possible (or a toy data set).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably many ways to archieve what you want. Maybe just read it in using `readLines`, then determine the indices of the two empty lines and use `read.csv` on the two subsets:

```
txt <- readLines(con=textConnection("1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8


a,b,c,d,e
f,g,h,i,j"))
read.csv(header=F, text=txt[1:which.max(txt=="")])
#   V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1  1  2  3  4
# 2  5  6  7  8
read.csv(header=F, text=txt[(which.max(txt=="")+2):length(txt)])
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
# 1  a  b  c  d  e
# 2  f  g  h  i  j
```

---

With regards to your added toy example:

```
txt <- readLines(con=textConnection("A  B  C  D #1st
1  2  3  4


A  B  C  D #2nd
5  6  7  8"))
txt <- sub("\\s+#.*$", "", txt) # delete comments if necessary
read.table(header=T, check.names = F, text=txt[1:which.max(txt=="")])
#   A  B  C  D
# 1 1  2  3  4
read.table(header=T, check.names = F, text=txt[(which.max(txt=="")+2):length(txt)])
#   A  B  C  D
# 1 5  6  7  8
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have edited my question with a toy data set.

Comment: Thanks, I added another example.

Answer (score 1):

That depends. If you know the row number where the first block ends and second one has no header, you can do

```
mydata <- read.csv('yourfile.csv', header=TRUE)
block1 <- mydata[1:18,]
block2 <- mydata[19:nrow(mydata)]
```

If your blocks have different structures, like different number of columns, and each block has its own column names, then it’s better to use readLines() function, and pass the result to read.csv.  How do you tell those blocks appart?

In reply to your comment:
Then it’s relatively easy. As Kota Mori pointed out,  read your data with blank likes. Assuming your first column has numeric values, and no NAs except in between your data sets,

```
mydata <- read.table('yourfile.csv', header=TRUE, blank.lines.skip = FALSE)
blines <- which(is.na(mydata[,1]))
data1 <- mydata[1:(blines[1]-1),]
data2 <- mydata[(blines[length(blines)]+1):nrow(mydata),]
```

you should alter the search pattern depending on your data.

Comment: Thank you for answer I have edited my question. Also since the first data set's rows varies I do not know the row number for when the second data set begins.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what data file you have.
If you have two empty rows between the two data, letting `blank.lines.skip = FALSE` in `read.csv()` would allow you to locate where to split the data.